# using Mathematica library in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to build a Math expression calculator in Java.

Is any way for using `Mathematica` libraries in `Java` program without instaling Mathematica on computer?

Comment: No. There is no way. Impossible.

Comment: It could be possible with the player (like free player with a signed library, or player pro with a non signed library), or with a future engine. This would be game changing in many fields that are "locked" to specific working environments. But WR has never been too enthusiastic about these interfacings. And so, for now it is not possible to have something similar to the mathworks mcr... (Which doesn't even need a signed library, extra cost, kind of thing...)

Comment: The website of Wolfram Research [mentions](http://www.wolfram.com/engine/?source=nav) products, such as the "Wolfram Engine Library" and SDKs, that may make this possible one day. But as far as I know these are not released as of yet.

Comment: @Pickett And when I saw it, I thought my world was about to change :-), but after discussing it with some more "knowledgeable people", although it was clear that the scope of these products was not yet very clear (or at least, to them), they all said that this would most likely be products to be integrated/used by editors of other products (that is medium to large scale businesses), and not really by individual users on a one case scenario... (it would be something like special licensing schemes, etc). But this was some time ago and probably the image is more clear now, and things have changed

Comment: @Pickett And if you read carefully the page you linked, you will notice that it indeed points out to something bigger than single user cases: "deployed products", "OEM applications", etc... The only answer I got from WR as a solution for this kind of needs, was "use the cloud", which is far from a realistic solution, when we need to make calls hundreds or thousands of times per second, for days in a row, as is typical in technical engineering needs.